# Get hours between a unix time value and now

Tags: php, unix, time, hour

I'm using the Highcharts library to create some nice looking reports.

I have a collection of unix time values and I need to convert them to the amount of hours between that date and "Now".

```
series: [{
    name: 'Fecha/Hora de Acceso',
    // Outputs: 2382374734 (a unix time)
    data: [<?php foreach($tutores as $t) echo $t['lastlogin'] . ','; ?>]
}]
```

Is there a simple way to do this using PHP? I'm looking for just a value like `34`. Not `34 Hours`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the PHP time() function to compare and divide the result by 3600 to get the difference in hours

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

```
<?php foreach($tutores as $t) {
    echo floor((time() - $t['lastlogin']) / 3600) . ',';
} ?>
```

EDIT: Updated to use floor() in example. Could also use round() or anything else to format the result as you want

Comment: This works, but returns a lot of decimal places. How can I just have it return `34` instead of `34.203611111`.

Comment: `floor()` or `round()` depending on the rounding style you need.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('@'.$t['lastlogin']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%h');
```

Comment: John I have one question: Do you have this piece of code ready in a txt file and just copy paste it whenever you find a question like this ?

Comment: I actually have an unpublished blog post for using DateTime and related classes that I regularly refer to. At some point I'll get around to publishing it. :)

Comment: "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2382374734)" To pass UNIX timestamps to the DateTime-constructor you have to prepend the timestamps with an `@` sign.

Comment: Correct. I have now added it.

Comment: The `DateInterval` returned by `diff` has the difference broken up into days, hours, minutes, etc. So the hours will never be more than 24. You need to add the days, multiply by 24 (with exceptions for DST) and add the hours. Or you could use @Nealio's code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could `DateTime::diff()`: http://php.net/datetime.diff

```
$input = 2382374734;

$old = new DateTime( '@' . $input );
$diff = $old->diff( new DateTime() );

echo sprintf( '%d is %d hours ago', $input, $diff->format( '%h' ) );
```

Comment: DateInterval stores the difference broken up into days, hours, etc. So the hours is not the TOTAL hours, it's the hours remaining after subtracting the days. See http://eval.in/18321